# how to use multiple parameters based on a certain value?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, array-formulas, gs-vlookup, multiple-conditions

I'm working on a tax sheet for personal use in Google Sheets. The hard thing is that the tax rate has been different for the last three years, making it hard for me to make the correct formula.

I have two tabs in the sheet

- Main sheet (showing taxes and tax rate

- Tax calculation sheet

The tax sheet has a calculation now based on a fixed percentage for taxes, but I want it to calculate based on the correct tax rate for the correct year, based on the date for the row.

**On the main sheet I have listed:**

A5 = Year 2017

A6 = Year 2018

A7 = Year 2019

B5 = 2017 tax calculations

B6 = 2018 tax calculations

B7 = 2019 tax calculations

C5 = 2017 Tax % rate

C6 = 2018 Tax % rate

C7 = 2019 Tax % rate

In the Tax sheet I add one row for each trade which includes the profit made - shown in the V column, then profits multiplied with the tax rate which is taking place in the W column. The code used today is `=$V9*24%`. The date for the trade is taking place in the H column. What I want to do is something like this:

> If the date is >=1/1/2017",$H$2:$H$991,"<1/1/2018, then multiply the
>   profits in V column with C5. 
> If the date is
>   '>=1/1/2018",$H$2:$H$991,"<1/1/2019, then multiply the profits in V column with C6. 
> If the date is >=1/1/2019",$H$2:$H$991,"<1/1/2020,
>   then multiply the profits in V column with C7.

All of these conditions need to be set in a single formula to be used in the W column.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(YEAR(H2:H), B5:C7, 2, 0)*W2:W))
```

[image: 0]

Answer (score 0):

At first sight sumifs should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

None of the suggestions above worked for me. You can download my sample file here to take a closer look:
https://www.excelforum.com/attachments/for-other-platforms-mac-google-docs-mobile-os-etc/658520d1579391027-google-sheet-how-to-use-multiple-parameters-based-on-a-certain-value-sample.xlsx